# Create Ubuntu scopes for websites

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development

How do you create a scope in Ubuntu for a simple website wrapper? Please don't judge me I am not a developer, just trying to create a scope for my blog with notifications when a new post is up.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, are you using scope in the sense like 'all the work that is involved"?  Also, "simple website wrapper"?  Please edit the question with less jargon.  At the moment, I don't know how to answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, what is the right documentation to create a scope for a website? I hope it makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use scopes to "wrap" a website. You would want a simple webapp for that.

Scopes are used for querying and displaying of remote content from a web services API e.g youtube, amazon, or querying a RSS or XML data feed of some kind etc. Scopes provide a way to render the raw data in a clean and consistent way.

If your blog has an RSS feed then you can most certainly create a scope for it. https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/scopes/tutorials/ is the best documentation to get going with scopes.